# Правописание НЕ с причастием и н/нн в причастии

Tags: орфография, частица-не, причастия, удвоенные-буквы

"А как выглядит она? (Не)чёса(н/нн)ая со сна, (не)накрашенная, (не)умытая!"

Уважаемые знатоки русского языка! Вот мало мне правил. Как бы вы написали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что для прилагательное **нечесаный** может переходить в причастие при наличии зависимых слов **в общем случае**:  **долго не чесать ― долго не чесанный.**

Зависимое слово ***со сна*** не меняет статус слова: **нечесаный** (прил.) ― **нечесаный** со сна (прил.)

Нельзя сказать *чесать со сна,* поэтому сначала образуется прилагательное **нечесаный (лохматый)**, а потом оно присоединяет собственное зависимое слово: **нечесаный со сна**.

http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=52#pp52

Примечание. Как видно из примеров, причастие опознается по наличию зависимых слов (**писанная маслом картина**).

Бывают, однако, редкие случаи, когда **зависимое слово не является признаком причастия.** Напр., следует писать: у него усики **явно крашеные** (ср. явно искусственные, где слово явно употреблено при прилагательном);

Answer (score 2):

***НЕ*** на двойное ***н*** не влияет, не приставка это - прилипшая частица (это то правило, которое Вы просите Вам не напоминать). Нет противопоставления и/или зависимых слов (есть и ещё тонкости, но они из высшей школы, типа наличие наречий меры и степени в качестве зависимых слов) - значит, проехали.

Слитно, стало быть, пишется в Вашем примере.

***НН*** зависит совсем от другого.

Только глагол "накрасить" имеет приставку - два ***н*** рисуем на автомате, а отглагольное прилагательное "чёсаный" (образовано от бесприставочного глагола несовершенного вида "чесать"), как только обзавелось зависимыми словами ("со сна"), обратно же на автомате конвертируется в причастие и обрастает дополнительным ***н***, такова уж его планида.

**ИТОГО**

*А как выглядит она? Нечёсанная со сна, ненакрашенная, неумытая!*

Comment: А мне кажется, что нечёсаная со сна=косматая (лохматая) со сна - прилагательное, это постоянный признак, зависимое слово не указывает на действие чесать, на время, скорее - на причину. Почему нечёсаная, косматая? со сна, только встала. не успела привести себя в порядок. В связи с изменением правил 2000 года не каждое зависимое слово влияет на написание -нн-, тольк в творит. падеже и указывающие на время. Не чёсанная кем-то, давно не чёсанная, но со сна нечёсаная. Можно сравнить с прилагательными на  -мый: нелюбимый в семье ребёнок и никем не любимый ребёнок. Логика та же.

Comment: А уж если сочли слово причастием, почему слитно с не? Тогда уж раздельно

Comment: Я о логике отнесения к прилагательным или причастиям в сравнении с прилагательным на -мый.

Comment: Люся, там Жасминчик примеры приводит, почему НЕ слитно: это ни то ни сё в чистом виде: полупричастие-полуприлагательное!

Comment: Ни то ни сё - так не бывает, это отглагольное прилагательное, и Вы это тоже чувствуете, потому что написали слитно - как прилагательное, но почему-то с -нн- как причастие, так тоже не бывает. Изменения 2000 года как раз склоняют к написанию с 1 -н-, если не на -ова-, нет зависимых слов в творит.пад. и указывающих на время, только такие зависимые слова превращают прилагательные в причастия.

Comment: Я спецьяльно влезла в школьную шпаргалку: как тока - так сразу: обросло отглагольное прилагательное зависимым словом - здрастье, уже причастье. Я написала как дышится! А теорий я не изучала; в школе по русскому была жирная единица, в институте - тройка, Валгина натянула. Нетеори(е)зибельная я! Практик мы сугубый!

Comment: Из справочника ЛОПАТИНА (не РОЗЕНТАЛЯ):http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=52#pp52  крашенные зелёной краской скамейки - это ПРИЧАСТИЕ,   есть зависимое слов (и никакого Т.п.). ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ. Как видно из примеров, причастие опознается по наличию зависимых слов. Бывают, однако, редкие случаи, когда ЗАВИСИМОЕ СЛОВО НЕ ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ ПРИЗНАКОМ ПРИЧАСТИЯ Напр., следует писать: у него усики явно крашеные (ср. явно искусственные, где слово явно употреблено при прилагательном); стены, раньше белёные, теперь покрыты зелёной краской (ср. стены, раньше белые).

Comment: Девочки, вы уж меня простите, но я не первый раз говорю, что действует сейчас не какой-либо справочник, а виноградовский словарь РАН 2000-2017 гг. Он есть на Академике.   https://pravopisanie.academic.ru/16/%C2%A7_058-069._%D0%94%D0%92%D0%9E%D0%99%D0%9D%D0%AB%D0%95_%D0%A1%D0%9E%D0%93%D0%9B%D0%90%D0%A1%D0%9D%D0%AB%D0%95#   Вот С.Кузьмина, соавтор Лопатина,  объясняет для образовательных учреждений , как пользоваться сводом: http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200003801

Comment: Отсюда понятно, что старыми правилами пользоваться можно факультативно. Пишущий должен иметь право на передачу языковых тонкостей, но нельзя его обязать проводить тонкий семантический или морфологический анализ, который он  не в состоянии сделать. В ряде случаев неизбежно условное решение. При написании н/нн в аффиксах  может быть оставлена доля свободы, факультативность. Это для непрофессионалов. Но у нас сайт ведь научный? И если профессионал отвечает непрофессионалу, он должен учесть ВСЕ новые веяния науки? Иначе зачем мы здесь? Погуглить по справочникам люди и сами могут.

Comment: Дорогие знатоки! Узнала много полезного и интересного из вашей дискуссии. Но чуть-чуть запуталась. Скажите, люди добрые, как написать простой смертной? "Нечёсаная со сна, ненакрашенная, неумытая!" Правильно?

Comment: Лена, по-видимому ближе всех к истине Люси. ***Нечёсаная со сна, ненакрашенная, неумытая!***

Comment: @ЕленаТаволга, см. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/436791/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F - старые правила не отменены! Значит, ***не чёсанная со сна***!

Answer (score 2):

**1) Всё ясно со словами ненакрашенная, неумытая.**

Это причастия, которые при отсутствии зависимых слов по значению близки к прилагательным и обозначают качественный признак,  а не признак по действию. Других факторов нет, НЕ в этом случае пишется слитно.

Две буквы НН выбираются по формальному признаку: наличие приставки, слово к исключениям не относится.

**2) А вот "нечесанная со сна" ― это интересный пример.**

Две буквы НН соответствуют наличию зависимого слова по тому же формальному признаку.  Но и НЕ с причастием можно написать раздельно, ориентируясь на зависимое слово.

**Но зависимые слова бывают разные**, и это сложный вопрос, так как решается тоже по-разному.

**1) Классический вариант**: НЕ пишется раздельно, если зависимое слово переходит из глагольного сочетания, например: не сдать работу вовремя ― не сданная вовремя работа.

2) В нашем случае нельзя сказать: **не чесать волосы со сна,** значит, сначала образовалось слово "нечесанная",  а потом оно получило **собственное** зависимое слово, которое уже не влияет на написание НЕ.

**3) Но, похоже, это слово вообще считает себя "независимым" от глагола**, например: давно (отроду) не чесать голову - давно (отроду) не чесанная голова. Вроде бы в этом случае нужно писать раздельно, но в текстах встречаются варианты, причем как в старых, так и новых (после 1956 года). Народ на форумах тоже в большом затруднении.

Примеры:

Сердце размеренно и мощно билось в груди, **отроду нечёсанная** грива грозно щетинилась. [Мария Семенова. Волкодав: Знамение пути (2003)]

Огромного роста, круглоголовый и **вечно нечёсанный**... Полюд приволок с собой бочонок и уселся на него у стола. [Алексей Иванов. Сердце Пармы (2000)]

Из-под моста встречу мне ― точно кусок земли ожил ― поднялся крепкий, **давно нечесанный**, небритый человек в широких синих штанах... [Максим Горький. Покойник (1913)]

Берендеи уставились друг на друга, запрокинув **нечесанные с вечера** бороды. [Евгений Лукин. Катали мы ваше солнце (1997)]

Скорик слегка наклонил голову, и как бы **давно не чесанные волосы** съехали на его массивный, далеко к темени взошедший лоб. [Виктор Астафьев. Прокляты и убиты. Книга первая. Чертова яма (1995)]

Зато Хрисанф ожил, засияли его эмалевые глаза, даже сивые кудри, **годами не чесанные,** загуляли, так вдруг загорелся старик. [Владимир Личутин. Крылатая Серафима (1977)]